# Fault Tolerance With MAAS and juju

Tags: juju, maas

I have juju installed on the MAAS server, is it possible to do fault tolerance ? If is it possible, how do I apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can model fault tolerance in both juju and MAAS. With MAAS you can set up multiple regions, while regions can be anything you want, they typically refer to an entire isolated power+networked area. (Imagine a region being a datacenter). If you configure MAAS in this way using it with juju becomes easy.

After running `juju bootstrap` you can run `juju ensure-ha` which will create a cluster of bootstrap nodes. By doing so, you'll have bootstrap node in an high availability configuration. You can even have the extra bootstrap nodes setup in competing regions in MAAS so even if one region goes dark your deployment is still available.

- See this link for more info on HA mode: https://jujucharms.com/docs/latest/juju-ha

Now, for when deploying with Juju, you can deploy multiple units of a service and have those units deployed on competing regions (just like with the bootstrap node) this ensures that if a region goes dark your deployment will still be operational.